# Use function defined in colab cell using that has javascript elements inside a python file

Tags: javascript, python, google-colaboratory

I am trying to use my laptop's webcam in Google Colab ([code snippet](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/snippets/advanced_outputs.ipynb#scrollTo=2viqYx97hPMi)) but I guess that approach has a limitation. It uses Javascript which can be executed inside the cell only. If the function containing the javascript is defined inside a python file and called, below error related to eval_js is returned.

```
File "/content/slowfast/my_module.py", line 57, in take_photo
    data = eval_js('takePhoto({})'.format(quality))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/google/colab/output/_js.py", line 36, in eval_js
    kernel = _ipython.get_kernel()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/google/colab/_ipython.py", line 24, in get_kernel
    return get_ipython().kernel
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'kernel'
```

Upon asking ChatGPT, it said to me the below information which seems to support the error.

`Ensure Execution in Colab Notebook Context: Make sure that the code snippet involving eval_js is executed within a Google Colab notebook cell. eval_js is designed to work in the Colab environment where it can communicate with the browser's JavaScript context. Running this code outside of Colab, or in an environment where the notebook's kernel isn't properly connected to the Colab frontend, will lead to failures.`

My requirement/ limitation is that I need to use an open-source library that works on image inputs and my local PC does not have enough GPU memory to run the code. So, I am trying to test it on Colab's HW. Is there any way to use the functions defined in the cell inside a Python file? That way, I guess I can minimize the code changes in the pipeline that is already written.